# Change meeting from an all day event to not an all day event

Tags: vba, outlook

I send a meeting to two recipients and have it show up as desired.

How do I find the meeting by date and time (same as when it was sent) and change it from being an all day event to not being an all day event?

```
Sub Appointment()

    Dim olApt As AppointmentItem

    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set olApt = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

    With olApt
        .Start = #3/10/2017 4:00:00 PM#
        .End = #3/3/1017 5:00:00 PM#
        .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
        .AllDayEvent = True
        .Subject = "OOO - Test"
        .Body = "Testing Stuff"
        .BusyStatus = olFree
        .ReminderSet = False
        .RequiredAttendees = "Placeholder" & ";" & " Placeholder"
        .Save
        .Send
    End With 
   
    Set olApt = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Function FindAppts(apptDate As Date, strSubject As String)

Dim myDate As Date
Dim myEnd As Date
Dim oCalendar As Outlook.Folder
Dim oItems As Outlook.Items
Dim oItemsInDateRange As Outlook.Items
Dim oFinalItems As Outlook.Items
Dim oAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim strRestriction As String

myStart = apptDate
myEnd = DateAdd("d", 30, myStart)

Debug.Print "Start:", myStart
Debug.Print "End:", myEnd

'Construct filter for the next 30-day date range
strRestriction = "[Start] >= '" & _
Format$(myStart, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AMPM") _
& "' AND [End] <= '" & _
Format$(myEnd, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AMPM") & "'"

'Check the restriction string
Debug.Print strRestriction

Set oCalendar = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
Set oItems = oCalendar.Items
oItems.IncludeRecurrences = False
oItems.Sort "[Start]"

'Restrict the Items collection for the 30-day date range
Set oItemsInDateRange = oItems.Restrict(strRestriction)

'Construct filter for Subject containing 'team'
Const PropTag  As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/"
strRestriction = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & PropTag _
    & "0x0037001E" & Chr(34) & " like '%' & strSubject & '%'"

'Restrict the last set of filtered items for the subject
Set oFinalItems = oItemsInDateRange.Restrict(strRestriction)
'Sort and Debug.Print final results
oFinalItems.Sort "[Start]"
For Each oAppt In oFinalItems
    Debug.Print oAppt.Start, oAppt.Subject
    If oAppt.Start = apptDate Then
        oAppt.Delete
    End If

Next
End Function
```

I modified this from the Office Dev Center: [Search the Calendar for Appointments Within a Date Range that Contain a Specific Word in the Subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867729.aspx)